# Non-English letters in html2text?

Tags: text-processing, locale, unicode, html

I'm making a script which uses `html2text`, however, it can't handle non-English letters. I'd like to use letters such as á, é í, ó ú, æ, ø, ö, ä, ð, þ. It just shows questions marks instead of the intended letters, and I have tried `tidy` but it just doesn't work the same way, so it's not something I'd like to use for this script.

Comment: I found two `html2text` tools, one written in Python another in C++ ... which one do you use.

Comment: Don't know what it's built in but according to the `man` page, "Arno Unkrig" and "Martin Bayer" wrote it.

Comment: @Scanlight after further research, it's not the Python one.

Comment: yes, it's the one written in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-utf8` and `-nobs`, it will be able to display special letters.

Comment: `-utf8` is not described in documentation but it's good if it works :) could you write more description / info about this options to make a complete answer?

Comment: -nobs          Do not use backspaces for boldface and underlining
  -ascii         Use plain ASCII for output instead of ISO-8859-1
  -utf8          Assume both terminal and input stream are in UTF-8 mode

Comment: Debian  version of html2text also can do input and output recoding (see
       /usr/share/doc/html2text/README.Debian for more info).  html2text tries
       to fetch encoding from HTML document. If encoding is not specified, you
       can use -ascii and -utf8 options.  Output is converted to user's locale
       charset (LC_CTYPE).

Comment: The original html2text doesn't have it. It is the debian version that contains all the goodies.